# No exceptions while running code in react js but not getting expected output

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am quite stumped while running Hello world program in react js with webpack

please find below attachment for project structure

[image]

When I execute, `npm run dev` command from cli, browser is launching but index.js value is not rendering, quite unsure what is wrong, as I am not seeing any exception in code either on cmd nor browser console

FYI:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {

  render () {
      return
       <div>
        <p>Hello, World!</p>;
        <h1>Hell yay !!</h1>
       </div>;
  }
}

render(<APP /> , document.getElementById("app"))
```

and index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>React.js using NPM, Babel6 and Webpack</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="app" />
 <script src="build/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `render(<APP />` what you actually have in your code? Shouldn't it be `<App />`?

Comment: @codecubed.io yes, but that should throw a `ReferenceError`. I think there's an issue at bundle.js

Comment: Did you rebuild your app?

Comment: I have changed to "render(<APP />" to "render(<App />", rebuilt and ran, then on browser console seeing error.. 'APP' is not defined

Comment: It is working now, with your suggested solution,  codecubed.io thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Is render( what you actually have in your code? Shouldn't it be ? -- codecubed.io commented above.

After following this suggestion, it worked, Credit goes to 'codecubed.io' Thank you again :)